# What is the difference between Dispatcher thread and UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

Is UI thread and Dispatcher thread are same in WPF or is there any difference?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) is responsible for managing the work for a thread.

The UI thread is the thread that renders the UI.

> The UI thread queues work items inside an object called a Dispatcher.
>   The Dispatcher selects work items on a priority basis and runs each
>   one to completion.  Every UI thread must have at least one Dispatcher,
>   and each Dispatcher can execute work items in exactly one thread.

[From this article. Read it for a more thorough description of the UI Rendering in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms741870(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 6):

UI thread is a general term (it's not specific to WPF) and describes a thread which has UI components associated with it. Usually, there is only one UI thread per application (in which case, it's called *the* UI thread), but there can be more, if different UI components (usually windows) are associated with different threads.

[`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) is the mechanism WPF uses to associate a component with a thread and to execute work on that thread. But there can also be a thread with a `Dispatcher`, but no associated UI components. In that case, it's a dispatcher thread, but not a UI thread.